# Unable to click outside popup(on homescreen) to dismiss the popup

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, popupwindow

I am trying to automate https://www.makemytrip.com/

A default popup appears for login. I want to close this popup and go to the home screen to search for the flight.
Below is the code I am trying to execute but it's not working-

```
private By getHomepage = new By.ByXPath(" //div[@class='imageSlideContainer']");
    
    public void setInputEmail(String username, String password) {
        driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("argument[0].click()", getHomepage);
       //driver.findElement(getHomepage).click();
```

[image]

Need to bypass this popup.

Comment: is it able to close manually?

Comment: Are you able to close the popup manually?

Comment: Try clicking on the landing container and this login popup should go away. You may use the following xpath to click on the landing container: //div[@data-cy='landingContainer']